# Zip I/O error: No such file or directory in bash script

Tags: bash, macos, zip

I've been writing some code to (mostly) automate password protecting and compressing/archiving folders and files. However, the code seems to hate me.

I've run it line by line, and it always chokes on the zip command, even when the `$file` and `$source` are correct and valid.

Any ideas?

Here's the source code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Drag in the source file"
read source
echo

echo "Drag in the destination file, or press enter to select the Desktop"
read destination
echo

if [ -z "$destination" ]
then destination="$PWD/Desktop"
echo "Destination is set to the desktop"
fi

echo "Type the name of the file to make"
read file

if [ -z "$file" ]
then file="archive"
echo "File name set to archive.zip"
fi

file="${destination}/${file}"

if [ -d $"source" ]
then zip -erj "$file" "$destination"
else zip -ej "$file" "$destination"
fi
```

Comment: zip is probably not on your path inside the script.  Try hard coding the path to zip to see if that helps.  If it does you can set the path in your script.

Comment: `then destination="$PWD/Desktop"` -- this is not the desktop. `$PWD` is the current working directory, it can be anything. The desktop is `$HOME/Desktop`. And this is a possible cause for the error as `zip` doesn't create the destination directory if it doesn't exist. Also, it seems you asked `zip` to archive `$destination` instead of `$source`.

Comment: @axiac Thanks! That seems to have solved it. Maybe create an answer so I can mark it as solved? Also, I'm pretty sure the syntax for zip is `zip destination source`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in your code:

```
if [ -z "$destination" ]
then destination="$PWD/Desktop"
echo "Destination is set to the desktop"
fi
```

`$PWD` is the current working directory. It is your home directory when you open a Terminal but it changes everytime you run `cd`.

The Desktop directory is `$HOME/Desktop`.

If you don't run the script from your home directory, most probably `$PWD/Desktop` doesn't exist and this is a cause for errors; `zip` doesn't attempt to create the destination directory for the archive you ask it to build. If the directory doesn't already exist it displays an error message and exits.

Another problem is on the invocation of `zip`:

```
if [ -d $"source" ]
then zip -erj "$file" "$destination"
else zip -ej "$file" "$destination"
fi
```

You probably want to archive the file `$source` or the files in the `$source` directory (if it is a directory) but you mistakenly put `$destination` as the file/directory to archive in the `zip` command line.

`if [ -d $"source" ]` -- it should be `"$source"`, otherwise the quote are useless and if `$source` contains spaces the script will exit with a syntax error.

One last thing: `zip` doesn't mind receiving `-r` in the command line when it is asked to archive only one file. You can replace the entire `if/else` block above with a single command:

```
zip -erj "$file" "$source"
```